# How to create bootable USB drive from DVD

Tags: fedora, iso-image, bootable-media, liveusb

I have a DVD with fedora 20 in it. My DVD drive doesn't work so I need to boot from an USB. I have copied the contents of the DVD into a USB drive and now how can I make this drive bootable?

Comment: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Live_USB You mat want to read this page.

Comment: I don't have an image file.I have a fedora installation DVD

Comment: You can always download the image. But then, having a dvd is the same thing.

Comment: how can I make a live USB from that DVD

Comment: But I have copied it's contents into a USB drive from another computer.

Answer (score 2):

Throw away the DVD and delete the files you copied from it. Download a new ISO from fedora. Let Universal USB Installer do all the work. You just need to point it at your ISO file and your USB stick.

http://fedoraproject.org/get-fedora

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **unetbootin**.

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

It is avaible for Linux, Windows and Mac.

First create image via dd command:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/cdrom of=cd.iso
```

Or if you have a directory that wish to create iso:

```
$ mkisofs -o cd.iso /your/directory
```

And then use **unetbootin**.

Comment: I don't have an image file.I have a fedora installation DVD .

Comment: @M.Tarun I updated the post. check it again

Comment: @M.Tarun dd command is available for windows too. http://sourceforge.net/projects/windd/

Comment: My DVD drive doesn't work.So I have copied it's contents into a USB drive from another computer. But the USB drive doesn't boot

Comment: @M.Tarun I updated the post . check it again.